# How to resolve the partition range error on haas - ERROR [42000] [Cloudera][Hardy] (80)

Tags: c#, sql, hadoop, hive, odbc

We are executing a Hive sql query on a Haas table that was working correctly for the last few months but now fails with below error -

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000] [Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Number of partitions scanned (=3011) on table 'cosmoss_job_notes_ext' exceeds limit (=3000). This is controlled on the metastore server by hive.metastore.limit.partition.request.)

I am connecting to the Haas table via ODBC connection. The connection opens properly but fails on the query execution.

This query fetches the set of rows for last 4 days on the table. We do not have access to the table and are looking to resolve this issue on the query level.

We have suggested to 'perform a query on a range of partitions (less than 3,000) then the query will run.' but need views on how we can modify the query on a range of partitions?

I can't put the exact query here hence Sample query is as below -

```
Select
haas_createdon AS record_created_date,
record_type AS record_type,
circuit_id AS prod_svce_id,
version_number AS version_number,
circuit_status AS circuit_status,
product_code AS product_code,
job_number AS job_number,
job_status AS job_status,
job_start_date AS job_start_date,
job_end_date AS job_end_date,
notes_creation_date AS notes_creation_date,
notes_update_date AS notes_update_date,
notes_sequence_no AS note_sequence_no,
note_text AS note_text,
haas_createdon AS created_date
From haasContainerName.tablename
where 
product_code IN ('Product Codes')
AND
substr(note_text, 1, 4) IN ('Note text')
AND 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(notes_creation_date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),' 19:00:00')) - (86400 * 4)
```

Comment: "Number of partitions scanned on table exceeds limit" returns a lot of search results that might help you

Comment: set hive.metastore.limit.partition.request=9000; and then run the sql and try

Comment: @KoushikRoy The problem is we don't have access to the table, and it seems to be a legacy table created long back. 
Is there any way to resolve this with the query itself?, adding any additional where clauses etc?

Comment: You  can create a new table with new partitions and then drop existing table